# how to relate 'publishe_db' model with User() model to let username1 username2 ...create here publish in django

Tags: python, django

## User() model this = from django.contrib.auth.models import User

## create class to add publication from the User

class publishe_db(models.Model):

```
title = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
body = models.TextField(max_length = 5600)
file = models.FileField()
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Comment: Kindly format your question properly and provide little more details

Comment: Could you add some more details about your question instead of just posting the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ForeignKey field of the django models.

Something like this :

```
def publishe_db(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    body = models.TextField(max_length = 5600)
    file = models.FileField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(user, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='posts')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

You can also get all the posts of a user using the related_name value like this:

```
user = User.objects.get(username='testuser')
testuser_posts = user.posts
```

Kindly check in reference and use on_delete and related_name as per your use case.

Reference : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey